# List of SDL Tridion References

Tags: 2011, 2013, 2009, 5.3

I'm trying to have a list of ***SDL Tridion Documentation References*** for easy usage.

Please list down all Tridion references based on Versions.

Comment: References in what sense? Documentation? People?

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Its about documentation references.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On top of what you have already answered yourself, only thing I could add is this site (tridion.stackexchange.com), and the following SDL Tridion related blogs:

- [Albert Romkes](http://albertromkes.wordpress.com)
- [Albert te Boekhorst](http://www.albertteboekhorst.com)
- [Alexander Klock](http://www.codedweapon.com)
- [Alvin Reyes](http://www.createandbreak.net)
- [Andrey Marchuk](http://amarchuk.blogspot.com)
- [Arjen Stobbe](http://80000ft.blogspot.com)
- [Asier Fernandez](http://www.asierfernandez.com)
- [Charles Guo](http://charles-blog.appspot.com/tag/tridion)
- [Chris Summers](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/author/chris.aspx)
- [Chris van Leeuwen](http://www.chrisvanleeuwen.net/)
- [Dominic Cronin](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog)
- [Elena Serghie](http://elenaserghie.blogspot.com)
- [Eric Huiza](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com)
- [Ferdinand Lugo](http://tridionnut.blogspot.com)
- [Hao Houang](http://randomtridionblogger.blogspot.com)
- [Jaime Santos Alcon](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com)
- [Jeremy Grand-Scrutton](http://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/)
- [John Winter](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/)
- [Jordi Vanderpooten](http://tridionrevealed.wordpress.com)
- [Julian Wraith](http://www.julianwraith.com/)
- [Manuel Garrido](http://tridionstrategist.blogspot.com)
- [Mihai Cadariu](http://yatb.mitza.net)
- [Monica Manzano](http://monicamanzano.blogspot.com)
- [Nuno Linhares](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/)
- [Peter Kjaer](http://pkjaer.wordpress.com)
- [Robert Curlette](http://www.curlette.com)
- [Robert Jin](http://rjin-tridion.blogspot.com/)
- [Taras Strypko](http://esteewhy.posterous.com)
- [TridionDeveloper.com](http://TridionDeveloper.com) (multiple people, among which myself ;o)
- [Tridion Talk (podcasts)](http://www.tridiontalk.com/)
- [Vinoth](http://tridionuser.blogspot.com)
- [Visvabalaji](http://stringwriter.com)
- [Vadym Vlasenko](http://vvlasenko.blogspot.com)
- [Vesa Paakkanen](http://idonotalwaystestmycode.blogspot.com)
- [Yoav Niran](http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/category/tridion/)
- [Pankaj Gaur](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/)

There are plans to create a more structured overview of SDL Tridion related information (which would give you all these links in a single site basically), by replacing the SDL Tridion World website, but there is no ETA. for them currently.

Comment: The new site is live now http://community.sdl.com you can find Tridion info in the Tridion Developer group, including feeds from the community blogs and this site.

Answer (score 10):

## List of SDL Tridion References:

- **[Tridion 2013](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US)** Documentation ([*Requires login*](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/documentation/sdltridion.aspx))
- **[Tridion 2011 SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US)** Documentation ([*Requires login*](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/documentation/sdltridion.aspx))
- **[Tridion 2011 Extensions](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/index.aspx)**
- **[5.3 & 2009 Extensions](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/index.aspx)**
- **[Documentation for a specific product release](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/index.aspx)** ([*Requires login*](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/about/access/index.aspx))

Answer (score 5):

I would also add [Angel Puntero's Snipt blog](https://snipt.net/Puntero/tag/tridion/?page=1) to the other answers to this question. He has consolidated a large number of useful Tridion related code snippets from a variety of sources including StackOverflow and the blogs listed in Bart's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your question asks for documentation based on versions"

- From 2011 upwards all SDL Tridion (and other related products) are online here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=login.html&destination=

**Note: A log in is required.**

- Pre 2011 all documentation was bundled with the software in the form of PDF, CHMs and Java Docs.   Actually I think these still exist for 2011, but the online version is much easier to use as it's searchable and updated regularly.