# Tridion Web CMS - Starting tutorial

Tags: 2011, java

I am planning to create my website in Tridion web CMS.I would like to know more about Tridion CMS.
Is it a hosted solution? or i can download code and customize and hosted our server?.

I can't get a download source code link on their website. Which is the simple getting started CMS?

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the community and the community would appreciate if you have done research for yourself, and then post relevant questions - See FAQ for asking question.
To help you clarify you on your basic questions - see my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "CMS?" Tridion would be overkill for a single personal site. With [hundreds](http://cmsmatrix.org) to choose from, the simplest getting started CMS depends on your role and needs.

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest following the official Tridion Training Curriculum.  It is created for this purpose of introducing new developers to Tridion and also walking them through how to build a website using the CMS.  It is a minimum of 3 full days and [available from SDL here](http://www.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-product/web-content-management/).

The next best thing is to find a simple website and try to re-create this site in Tridion - starting with Page Types, Schemas, and then moving onto coding.  The best resource for this would be a colleague sitting next to you to show you how to do this and walk you through these steps.  This proces will take anywhere from 3 days to 2 weeks, depending how much time you put in and how complex the site is.  That should cover the basic features of Tridion.  However, the Tridion CMS suite is getting broader and adding new products on every year.  To go into more advanced topics such as Web Service APIs and automation it can take anywhere from 3 weeks to 6 weeks to have a good understanding of all the pieces and how it fits.

What I see is that new developers have a much harder time with the concepts (Pages / Component Presentations / Broker / etc) than the technical programming parts.  For this reason it is most helpful to follow the official Tridion training course or have a colleague walk you through all the steps.

Then, after this, you can follow the Tridion documentation or ask here on StackOverflow for more specific questions.

Answer (score 8):

Tridion CMS is a completely proprietary software and no code will be provided.
Also their is no concept of trial version or free developer download etc. and you have to get the licenses to get your hands down on it - See [**HERE**](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/855/does-sdl-offer-a-free-developer-download/856#856)

Also, this essentially a hosted solution which can be hosted in Cloud or on your local servers provided you have valid licenses purchased.

To start learning on SDL Tridion, there are few resource available on the internet - few of them are needing login and few are public - For a complete list of resource or study material you may want to read this Question [**HERE**](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/are-there-any-sources-of-good-study-materials-for-sdl-tridion-2011-templating/1336#1336) And [**HERE**](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/66/list-of-sdl-tridion-references/1279#1279)